# Can't use vuetify's icons

Tags: vue.js, icons, vuetify.js

I tried the following documentation steps :

```
$ yarn add @mdi/font -D
// OR
$ npm install @mdi/font -D
// src/plugins/vuetify.js

import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css' // Ensure you are using css-loader
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'

Vue.use(Vuetify)

export default new Vuetify({
  icons: {
    iconfont: 'mdi', // default - only for display purposes
  },
})
```

Once I'm done I try using the mdi icons inside `<v-icon>` and they show as squares, as if It is not recognizing the icon I am passing to it.

```
<v-icon large color="green darken-2">mdi-pencil</v-icon>
```

What's wrong?

Edit: Yep, I tried using the icon without the 'mdi' in front of the name of the icon

Comment: Can you inspect the icon and see if the font family is being applied to it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib/framework';

try importing Vuetify this way.

Comment: That breaks my app